# How to use an alias instead of a FQN in the _class field in Elastic + SpringBoot (Spring Data)

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.8 (Spring Data) + Elastic(Search).
While I'm storing data in ES, I've noticed a fully qualified name of the java class is being stored as _source._class.
I was wondering if there is any way to change it for an *alias*.
Here is an example:

```json
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 23,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "ref",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "5518588",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "_class": "com.test.domain.Ref",
                    "id": 5518588,
                    "lang": "el",
                    "lastProcessed": 1644830564198
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...